# Word the texture of food, like leeks: slippery with a hint of chewiness and crunchiness

Tags: single-word-requests, food

Looking for a word that would best describe the texture of leeks, particularly noticeable in my experience in some Chinese dishes.

When the leeks are a bit slippery with a very slight note of chewiness and crunchiness, that's the best description I could come up with.

There may be no better word than these three, but I somehow get the feeling I'm missing one..

Comment: Why do people think there should be a word for every possible experience? Put some work in, find an apt simile or a metaphor. These work ten times harder than a word few people will understand—if one even exists for what you want. Such a word is a ball that clunks into a losing slot on a roulette wheel nearly every time, and pays off poorly even when it wins.

Comment: I may have to eat my hat, but  you may have to settle for *leek-like.* :-)

Comment: You may have to settle for *something*-like, although there may be a very obscure word. This is a useful list but I can't see anything directly relevant: https://www.macmillandictionary.com/thesaurus-category/british/words-used-to-describe-the-state-or-consistency-of-food